# Remove uiview from uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I added UIView

```
AddViewController *addViewControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"add"];

[self.view addSubview:addViewControl.view];
```

How to remove it.

```
[addViewControl removeFromParentViewController];
```

Does not remove.

Answer (score 1):

To remove view you should call:

```
[addViewControl removeFromSuperView].
```

This remove UIView from superview

This code:

```
[addViewControl removeFromParentViewController];
```

you should use when you want to remove viewController from view hierarchy

Comment: I need to remove it and then re-create to perform -(void)viewDidLoad